# Reprojecting Nat Earth Raster to Wagner VII

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, gdal

While trying to reproject a raster file from Natural Earth (HYP_HR_SR_OB_DR) to a Wagner VII projection, QGIS 3.12 just throws an error. Other projections work out fine, mostly.

This is the GDAL call

```
gdalwarp -t_srs ESRI:54076 -r near -te -22077666.393789396 -9040858.441675251 18287107.47227834 10317214.927558815 -of GTiff 
    "C:/HYP_HR_SR_OB_DR.tif" C:/981cf88244ae43529643eef67d033744/OUTPUT.tif
```

Produces this error

```
ERROR 1: Too many points (10201 out of 10201) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.
```

Dataset is accessible here, comes as *+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs* :

https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/raster/HYP_HR_SR_OB_DR.zip

Also tried to do the same in R using the raster package, but there the result is just an empty raster.

```
projectRaster(HYP_HR_SR_OB_DR,crs = "+proj=wag7 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs",over = TRUE)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Wagner VII is not converging which is usually an edge condition - I can get Wagner IV (EPSG:54074) to work either with the raster or with vector data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not sure if I understand correctly, though. Tried Wagner IV and it worked like a charm. However for Wagner VII: Is there a way around this or is the operation itself impossible?

Comment: I don't know enough about Wagner VII to know where it's limits are I'm afraid

Comment: Alright, thanks. Guess I'll just settle with another projection.